# Loading a dll with LoadLibraryA and then reading variables inside of it

Tags: c++, dll

I've looked around, and gotten to the point where I can load a DLL and use `GetProcAddress()` to find the address of an exported function. The part I'm stuck on is when I print out the address of the function, I get a ton of `0`s (this many to be exact: `0000000000000000`). In the end, I'm trying to read the name of a char that's in there.

`.hpp` file:

```cpp
typedef char* (*t_Username)();

extern t_Username GetUsername;
```

I'm not really sure what this does since I got it from a "base", if you will.

`.cpp` file:

```cpp
t_Username GetUsername;

std::string test = "";

int main()
{
    auto dll = LoadLibraryA("DLL.dll");

    GetUsername = (t_Username)GetProcAddress(ORACLE, "GetUsername");

    std::cout << GetUsername;

    test = "Hello " + std::string(GetUsername());

    std::cout << test;
}
```

My DLL:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

void onAttach() {
    const char* GetUsername = "whatever.f";
    std::cout << GetUsername << std::endl;
    Sleep(100000000000);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstDll,
    DWORD dwReason,
    LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstDll);
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)onAttach, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Before I added the char to the void, I had it print a word, and that worked fine.

Comment: `GetProcAddress` _"...If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress

Comment: ill add this and see what i get

Comment: @MeatMan This code is full of mistakes. You are trying to import a `GetUsername()` **function** from the DLL, but the DLL code shown is not exporting a `GetUsername()` **function** . There is a `GetUsername` **variable** that is local to `onAttach()` and can't be exported (and BTW, `onAttach()` has the wrong signature for `CreateThread()` - get rid of the `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` typecast and the compiler would have told you that). Also, when calling `LoadLibrary()`, you save the returned handle to a variable `dll`, but you are then passing a different variable `ORACLE` to `GetProcAddress()`.

Comment: i tried change the var names when posting but i forgot one, ORACLE is the name of the var instead of dll, whats wrong with the create thread? and on top of that should i just make a new void named GetUsername?

Comment: also im getting the error code 127( looked it up and it said that the dll exists but the function is missing, witch makes me thing that i need to make a void named GetUsername